# Does the Transform() function decrease the frame rate of real-time video? Pin

Tags: video, media, directshow

I have a question related to DirectShow transform filter.

I use USB2.0 camera to get the real-time video at 30fps (1920x1080) and I want to process the video image by inserting a transform filter. But after the insertion, the frame rate is decreased. For example, the processing time is about 15ms, then the frame rate will drop to 1000/(33.3+15)=20.8fps. As if getting video data and processing video data are executed synchronously.

How can I get the asynchronous execution and get a higher frame rate?

Answer (score 2):

If your transform function is slow (e.g. slow algorithm or slow pc) then yes, you will get a decreased frame rate. The source filter will skip frames in this case.

Even with an async handling you will run into problems. If your camera is capturing 30 fps but your transform function can only process 20 frames per second, you have 10 frames every second you need to process later. And with a FullHD image, that is a lot of data, to cache for later processing!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can understand the situation which you describe.But now my processing algorithm just takes 10ms so the frame rates shouldn't be effected.If  taking video datas and processing data can be run Simultaneously,10ms will be hide.The question is how i achieve that.

Comment: Do you have other filters in the graph, like color conversion or writing the image data to a file? You need to look at the whole process. Does your Graph has 30 fps without your transform? Sadly I have seen USB2.0 Cameras with "to smart" drivers doing some transformations internally, so they not really can produce the configured fame rate.

Answer (score 0):

i found that when previewing video, using the pin(whose name is L"Preview") of the Filter(whose name is "Smart Tee") to build a graph is much better than using the pin(whose name is L"Capture") of the Filter(whose name is "Smart Tee").